# Move x label from right to left end of axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels

I feel like this is a very simple question, but I haven't found a simple answer so far. How can I move the x label on the following plot from the right end of the axis to the left?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=0.9\linewidth,height=0.7\linewidth,
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$(x+1)^2$,
        xmin=-2.1,xmax=0.05,
        ymin=-0.05,ymax=1.1,
        xtick={-2,-1,0},ytick={0,0.5,1},
        axis lines=center,
        thick,every tick/.style={thin}]

    \addplot[blue,samples=100] {(x+1)^2};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility:

```
xlabel style={at={(0,0)},above right,yshift=10pt}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=0.9\linewidth,height=0.7\linewidth,
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$(x+1)^2$,
        xmin=-2.1,xmax=0.05,
        ymin=-0.05,ymax=1.1,
        xtick={-2,-1,0},ytick={0,0.5,1},
        axis lines=center,
        thick,every tick/.style={thin},
        xlabel style={at={(0,0)},above right,yshift=10pt}
    ]

    \addplot[blue,samples=100] {(x+1)^2};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! How come this doesn't work when moving it directly behind `xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$(x+1)^2$,`?

Comment: Because `axis lines` positions the axis labels too. So you have to move the `xlabel` after `axis lines=center`.